# difference between number in the same column using AWK command

Tags: awk

I have a file containing one column of number:

```
1
2
4
7
10
12
```

and i want output like below

```
1
3
2
```

e.g
I need difference of each two iteration.

like `2-1=1` , `7-4=3`, `12-10=2`

Comment: And what have you tried before?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR%2{x=$0;next}{print $0-x}' File
```

For the odd lines, save the line (number) to variable `x`. For even lines, print the difference using previously saved `x`

Comment: Sane approach (+1). For kicks, let me mention an insane GNU sed approach: `sed 'N; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/echo $((\2 - \1))/e'` -- this doesn't warrant an answer of its own, but it is beautiful enough in its horror that I don't want it lost to the ages. Side note: You may want to consider special handling for files that have an odd number of lines.